# How to customize api with resource on collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a collection on my controller as below :

```
 $data = Accommodation::with(['city','accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function($query) use($from_date,$to_date){
    $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
    $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    }])    
    ->get();
 return new FilterResource($data);
```

and here is my filter resource

```
  public function toArray($request)
    {
    //return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id'           => $this->id,
            'costumfields' => 'somecostumfields'
        ];
    }
```

Now I want to customize my resource so that I can add some custom fields to it and customize the current fields on the api but this code gives me the error below :

> "message": "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.",

Comment: Try `dd($request)` inside `toArray()`. Is an id set?

Comment: if it's array your getting in toArray then you can use foreach to get dynamic name of keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are returning a collection it should be:

```
return FilterResource::collection($data);
```

Comment: yes thanks i should have sent that as collection in my controller thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel Eloquent `get()` functions returns a collection.

**Soulutions**

1. If you want to return all the accommodation as an array, you need to call `collection()` on the resource.

```php
return FilterResource::collection($data);
```

2. If you want to get one `Accommodation`, you need to call `first()` on the Eloquent query.

```php
$accommodation = Accommodation::with([
    'city',
    'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function($query) use($from_date,$to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    }])    
    ->first();

 return new FilterResource($accommodation);
```